# How to array the numbers like a bowtie shape in c

Tags: c

[image]

I'm trying to arrange numbers in a nxn(n is odd number) matrix with bow tie shapes. (like fig.)

Trying to 5x5 matrix set coordinates but no result.

my code:

```
bowtie {
  int a[5][5] = {{
                     0,
                 },
                 {
                     0,
                 },
                 {
                     0,
                 },
                 {
                     0,
                 },
                 {
                     0,
                 }};

  int i, j;
  int num = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i <= 2)  // y>=0 - coordinate(2d)
    {
      for (j = i; j <= 2; j++)  // x<=0, y>=0 Quadrant 2
      {
        a[i][j] = num;
        num++;
      }
      for (j = 4 - i; j > i; j++)  // Quadrant 1

      {
        a[i][j] = num;
        num++;
      }
    } else                              // y<0
      for (j = 4 - i; j <= 4 - i; j++)  // Quadrant 3
      {
        a[i][j] = num;
        num++;
      }

    for (j = i; j >= i; j++)  // Quadrant 2
    {
      a[i][j] = num;
      num++;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 5; j++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `bowtie`?

Comment: You have several reasons to write out of your array, see my answer also giving a proposal where the size is received in argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop

> ```
>        for (j = 4 - i; j > i; j++)  // Quadrant 1
> ```

is wrong because *j* starts at 4 (*i* valuing 0) being the last valid index then never stop to grow producing an undefined behavior when you go out of the array

The loop

> ```
>        for (j = 4 - i; j <= 4 - i; j++)  // Quadrant 3
> ```

is strange because the last possible value is the first one, so this is not a loop but just its body executed with `j = 4 - i`

The loop

> ```
>     for (j = i; j >= i; j++)  // Quadrant 2
> ```

is like the first and makes *j* incompatible with the array dimensions

---

A proposal where the size in given in argument and can be odd or even :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage %s <size>\n", *argv);
  else {
    int n;

    if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1) || (n < 1))
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid size %s\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      int a[n][n];
      int v = 0; /* the value 1.. to put in the cells */
      int empty; /* the empty height */
      int i,j;

      /* first half and may be center */
      empty = -1;

      for (j = 0; j <= (n-1)/2; ++j) {
        empty += 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i][j] = a[n - i - 1][j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++][j] = ++v;
      }

      if ((n & 1) == 0)
        empty += 1;

      /* second half */
      for (; j < n; ++j) {
        empty -= 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i][j] = a[n - i - 1][j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++][j] = ++v;
      }

      /* show result */
      for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
          if (a[i][j] == 0)
            fputs("    ", stdout); /* witdh = 4 compatible with a size up to 43 */
          else
            printf("% 4d", a[i][j]); /* width = 4 compatible with a size up to 43 */
        }
        putchar('\n');
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall b.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
   1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 2
   1   3
   2   4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 3
   1       5
   2   4   6
   3       7
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 4
   1           9
   2   5   7  10
   3   6   8  11
   4          12
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 5
   1              13
   2   6      10  14
   3   7   9  11  15
   4   8      12  16
   5              17
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 6
   1                  19
   2   7          15  20
   3   8  11  13  16  21
   4   9  12  14  17  22
   5  10          18  23
   6                  24
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 7
   1                      25
   2   8              20  26
   3   9  13      17  21  27
   4  10  14  16  18  22  28
   5  11  15      19  23  29
   6  12              24  30
   7                      31
```

---

If you do not accept even size

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage %s <size>\n", *argv);
  else {
    int n;

    if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1) || (n < 1) || ((n & 1) == 0))
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid size %s\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      int a[n][n];
      int v = 1; /* the value 1.. to put in the cells */
      int empty; /* the empty height */

      /* first half more center */
      empty = -1;

      for (int j = 0; j <= n/2; ++j) {
        int i;

        empty += 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i][j] = a[n - i - 1][j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++][j] = v++;
      }

      /* second half */
      for (int j = n/2 + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        int i;

        empty -= 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i][j] = a[n - i - 1][j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++][j] = v++;
      }

      /* show result */
      for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
          if (a[i][j] == 0)
            fputs("    ", stdout);
          else
            printf("% 4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall o.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Usage ./a.out <size>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1
   1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 2
invalid size 2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 3
   1       5
   2   4   6
   3       7
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 5
   1              13
   2   6      10  14
   3   7   9  11  15
   4   8      12  16
   5              17
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 17
   1                                                             145
   2  18                                                     130 146
   3  19  33                                             117 131 147
   4  20  34  46                                     106 118 132 148
   5  21  35  47  57                              97 107 119 133 149
   6  22  36  48  58  66                      90  98 108 120 134 150
   7  23  37  49  59  67  73              85  91  99 109 121 135 151
   8  24  38  50  60  68  74  78      82  86  92 100 110 122 136 152
   9  25  39  51  61  69  75  79  81  83  87  93 101 111 123 137 153
  10  26  40  52  62  70  76  80      84  88  94 102 112 124 138 154
  11  27  41  53  63  71  77              89  95 103 113 125 139 155
  12  28  42  54  64  72                      96 104 114 126 140 156
  13  29  43  55  65                             105 115 127 141 157
  14  30  44  56                                     116 128 142 158
  15  31  45                                             129 143 159
  16  32                                                     144 160
  17                                                             161
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

From you remark

> 'int a[n][n];' has problem.

probably you compiled in C++ rather than C, but it is easy to change that :

- replace `int a[n][n];` by `int * a = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));`
- replace each form `a[x][y]` by `a[(x)*n+y]`
- add a `free(a);` at the end

For instance if I do that on the proposal only accepting odd size :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage %s <size>\n", *argv);
  else {
    int n;

    if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1) || (n < 1) || ((n & 1) == 0))
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid size %s\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      int * a = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));
      int v = 1; /* the value 1.. to put in the cells */
      int empty; /* the empty height */

      /* first half more center */
      empty = -1;

      for (int j = 0; j <= n/2; ++j) {
        int i;

        empty += 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i*n+j] = a[(n - i - 1)*n+j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++*n+j] = v++;
      }

      /* second half */
      for (int j = n/2 + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        int i;

        empty -= 1;

        for (i = 0; i != empty; ++i)
          a[i*n+j] = a[(n - i - 1)*n+j] = 0;
        for (int k = n - empty*2; k; --k)
          a[i++*n+j] = v++;
      }

      /* show result */
      for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
          if (a[i*n+j] == 0)
            fputs("    ", stdout);
          else
            printf("% 4d", a[i*n+j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
      }

      free(a);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But 'int a[n][n];' has problem. I use visual studio. Using this program has problem to run?

Comment: @ReeMae `a[n][n]` has problem in C++, not in C, and you used the tag C

Comment: @ReeMae I edited my answer to add a solution without using `int a[n][n];`